# How to change TextInputLayout or AutoCompleteTextView's ripple color in Java?

Tags: android, material-design

Consider the following TextInputLayout with AutoCompleteTextView:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Value"
    android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/inputEditor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="none"
        />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

When users click the AutoCompleteTextView, a ripple will expand and fill the AutoCompleteTextView:

[image]

How do you change the color of the ripple in Java/Kotlin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the color of a AutoCompleteTextView turned out to be trickier than expected.

## Is there a public API?

TextInputLayout allows changing the background color via [`Text.setBoxBackgroundColor(color)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout#setBoxBackgroundColor(int)). However this method only works with the filled style and not the outline style. I tried it out anyways; the result looks so bad I'm not going to paste the abomination here to save your eyes from permanent damage.

The material design library will auto-inflate [`MaterialAutoCompleteTextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/MaterialAutoCompleteTextView) in place of `AutoCompleteTextView`. I can call `MaterialAutoCompleteTextView.setSupportBackgroundTintList(tint)` to tint the background. The doc redirects me to call `ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(view, tint)` instead.

```
view.setSupportBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN))
ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(view, ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN))
```

Result:
[image]

I tried both methods. Sadly, this API only applies the tint when the ripple is in progress. It also causes the background to draw under the hint.

Since the public API doesn't work, let's explore some <strike>hacks</strike> workarounds.

## Clone the background

I used a debugger to see exactly what AutoCompleteTextView uses for its background. Turns out it is a 2-layer LayerDrawable, with the first layer being a RippleDrawable and the second layer being a [CutoutDrawable](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/textfield/CutoutDrawable.java#L38).

2-layer LayerDrawable:
[image]

1st layer - RippleDrawable:
[image]

2nd layer - CutoutDrawable:
[image]

I only need to change the RippleDrawable's color. So I `mutate()` the LayerDrawable and target the RippleDrawable.

```
      (view.background as? LayerDrawable)
          ?.let { it.mutate() as? LayerDrawable }
          ?.let {
            for (i in 0 until it.numberOfLayers) {
              val d = it.getDrawable(i)
              if (d is RippleDrawable) {
                d.setColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN))
              }
            }
            view.background = it
          }
```

Result:
[image]

I think we're on the right track; the hint text is now tinted, but the CutoutDrawable is still losing all its state and is not cutting out the hint's area correctly.

## Mutate the background directly

Since CutoutDrawable does not override [`Drawable.inflate(Resources, XmlPullParser, AttributeSet)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable#inflate(android.content.res.Resources,%20org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.util.AttributeSet)), I think AutoCompleteTextView's background is always created in Java and not a shared XML Drawable like traditional Drawable resources in `R.drawable.*`. So it should be safe to remove the `.mutate()` call.

```
      (view.background as? LayerDrawable)
          ?.let {
            for (i in 0 until it.numberOfLayers) {
              val d = it.getDrawable(i)
              if (d is RippleDrawable) {
                d.setColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN))
              }
            }
          }
```

Result:
[image]

And voila! The AutoCompleteTextView's ripple can now be changed to any color in Java/Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

to do this in code you could use one of the constructor methods for the widget that allows the adding of a style, but those depend in specific api levels [21 to 24 depending on what is used]

[widget constructors](https://blog.danlew.net/2016/07/19/a-deep-dive-into-android-view-constructors/)

[journaldev](https://www.journaldev.com/19911/android-material-design-button-style-design)
"colorControlHighlight"   in the app style

```
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/design_default_color_background</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I know how to change the color in XML/themes. However, I'm looking for a solution in Java/Kotlin.

Comment: you mean programmatically?